# How to integrate all my different logins on Stack Exchange to a single one

Tags: discussion

On various occasions, I have created multiple logins on Stack Exchange via Google, Facebook, and email ids.

How can I integrate them under a single account which would gain all the reputation, comments, questions asked, bounties, tags, activity, badges, profile information, responses, votes, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

First sign into one of your accounts, visit the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’.

Then after you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts.